# "Update requires a valid InsertCommand" error when trying to create new lines in table

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Please be patient with me, I'm genuinely trying to make this as condensed as possible.

I've created a WPF window which creates a datagrid based on a table selected from a database. I do this by setting the datacontext of the window and then binding the datagrid's ItemSource to a table within that context  (OrdersViewModel).

ReceiveOrderDialogWindow.xaml.cs

```
    this.DataContext = new OrdersViewModel("Orders");
```

ReceiveOrderDialogWindow.xaml

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="datatable" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl}"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"/>
```

Then once the user confirms their choice, I call my update function from inside OrdersViewModel through an ICommand.

```
    Db.UpdateTable(SubVwr.Tables[0].UpdateTableQuery, SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl);
```

This is all a working to update existing rows, except I can't add any new rows.

UpdateTable method

```
public void UpdateTable(TableQuery query, DataTable tbl)
{
    if (query.Qry != "")
    {
        if (IsConnOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                UpdateCmd.CommandText = query.Qry;
                for (int i = 0; i < query.Prms.Count; i++)
                {
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter());
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters[i].ParameterName = "@" + query.Prms[i].Col;
                    UpdateCmd.Parameters[i].SourceColumn = query.Prms[i].Col;
                }
                DA.Update(tbl);
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Msg = "Error: " + ex.Number + " " + ex.Message + " from Qry = " + query.Qry;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Msg = "Error: " + ex + " " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Msg = "Not Connected";
        }
    }
```

---

I've done some research on where this error comes from, and potential solutions.

I know for example that I should implement something along the lines of:

```
MySqlCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new MySqlCommandBuilder(DA);
DA.UpdateCommand = cmdBldr.GetInsertCommand();
```

But the issue is then that Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

---

**Requested information**

query.Qry is as follows:

```
        UpdateTableQuery.Qry = @"
UPDATE
`n2000`.`lines`
SET 
`olID` = @olID,
`QtyPer` = @QtyPer,
`QtyRcvd` = @QtyRcvd,
`DateRcvd` = @DateRcvd,
`pid` = @pid,
`PricePer` = @PricePer,
`ItemETA` = @ItemETA,
`Note` = @Note,
`Rev` = @Rev
WHERE `olID` = @olID;
";
```

[Error message I receive. printed to console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT6zC.png)

Comment: what is the value of `query.Qry`?

Comment: I'll post it now

Comment: What is the error? Looks like a syntax error to me, I don't think column names should be enclosed in single quotes on MySql. And you data adapter needs an InsertCommand to be able to handle new rows. And their RowState must be "Added", are they?

Comment: Alright I posted the error. 
Also I'm sorry , I'm trying but I don't fully understand what exactly you're saying. bear with me. I'm not sure how to go about getting an InsertCommand apart from the solution I tried already. Not sure what you mean by RowState must be "Added"

Comment: You should do some research about how data adapters work. It will be much easier to use them. Take a look at a [sample app I have on GitHub](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid) . It uses Sqlite for simplicity but if it were hooked up to MySql the code would be nearly identical - all ADO.Net providers use nearly identical code, just different prefixes.